# How to Calculate Non-Cumulative Values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate non cumulative values of my budget (denoted by NC_Budget) for each month
Here's what my table currently looks like:

```
YEAR MONTH ACCOUNT  A_DESCRIPTION O_DESCRIPTION BUDGET NC_BUDGET
2023    01  23  Salary_Employee_1   95684 - Jack's  10  0
2023    01  24  Salary_Employee_2   95684 - Jack's  20  0
2023    01  25  Salary_Employee_3   95684 - Jack's  30  0
2023    01  26  Salary_Employee_4   95684 - Jack's  40  0
2023    01  27  Salary_Employee_5   95684 - Jack's  50  0
2023    02  23  Salary_Employee_1   95684 - Jack's  60  0
2023    02  24  Salary_Employee_2   95684 - Jack's  70  0
2023    02  25  Salary_Employee_3   95684 - Jack's  80  0
2023    02  26  Salary_Employee_4   95684 - Jack's  90  0
2023    02  27  Salary_Employee_5   95684 - Jack's  100 0
```

1. To calculate NC_BUDGET of month 01: NC_BUDGET is the same value as
   Budget.
2. To calculate NC_BUDGET of month 02: NC_BUDGET = BUDGET (of
   month 02) - Budget (of month 01)

This is what the NC_Budget column should look like:

```
YEAR MONTH ACCOUNT  A_DESCRIPTION O_DESCRIPTION BUDGET NC_BUDGET
2023    1   23  Salary_Employee_1   95684 - Jack's  10  10
2023    1   24  Salary_Employee_2   95684 - Jack's  20  20
2023    1   25  Salary_Employee_3   95684 - Jack's  30  30
2023    1   26  Salary_Employee_4   95684 - Jack's  40  40
2023    1   27  Salary_Employee_5   95684 - Jack's  50  50
2023    2   23  Salary_Employee_1   95684 - Jack's  60  50
2023    2   24  Salary_Employee_2   95684 - Jack's  70  50
2023    2   25  Salary_Employee_3   95684 - Jack's  80  50
2023    2   26  Salary_Employee_4   95684 - Jack's  90  50
2023    2   27  Salary_Employee_5   95684 - Jack's  100 50
```

Here's the code to create the table & insert the dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE BudgetTable (
    Year_Key NUMBER(4, 0) NOT NULL,
    Month_Key VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
    Account_Code NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Account_Description VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    Organzation_Description VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    Budget_Cumulative NUMBER NOT NULL,
    NC_Budget NUMBER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '01', 23, 'Salary_Employee_1', '95684 - Jack''s', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '01', 24, 'Salary_Employee_2', '95684 - Jack''s', 20, 0);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '01', 25, 'Salary_Employee_3', '95684 - Jack''s', 30, 0);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '01', 26, 'Salary_Employee_4', '95684 - Jack''s', 40, 0);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '01', 27, 'Salary_Employee_5', '95684 - Jack''s', 50, 0);

INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '02', 23, 'Salary_Employee_1', '95684 - Jack''s', 60, 0);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '02', 24, 'Salary_Employee_2', '95684 - Jack''s', 70, 0);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '02', 25, 'Salary_Employee_3', '95684 - Jack''s', 80, 0);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '02', 26, 'Salary_Employee_4', '95684 - Jack''s', 90, 0);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative, NC_Budget) VALUES (2023, '02', 27, 'Salary_Employee_5', '95684 - Jack''s', 100, 0);
```

This is a small sample of my large data set so I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

I tried this but it's not efficient

```
MERGE INTO BudgetTable BT
USING (
    SELECT
        b1.Year_Key,
        b1.Month_Key,
        b1.Account_Code,
        CASE
            WHEN TO_NUMBER(b1.Month_Key) = 1 THEN b1.Budget_Cumulative
            ELSE b1.Budget_Cumulative - COALESCE(b2.Budget_Cumulative, 0)
        END AS New_NC_Budget
    FROM BudgetTable b1
    LEFT JOIN BudgetTable b2 ON 
        b1.Account_Code = b2.Account_Code 
        AND b1.Year_Key = b2.Year_Key 
        AND TO_NUMBER(b1.Month_Key) = TO_NUMBER(b2.Month_Key) + 1
) t
ON (BT.Year_Key = t.Year_Key AND BT.Month_Key = t.Month_Key AND BT.Account_Code = t.Account_Code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET BT.NC_Budget = t.New_NC_Budget;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're better off not storing `NC_Budget` in the table at all. Instead, simply compute it at query time:

```
SELECT Year_Key
       Month_Key,
       Account_Code,
       Account_Description,
       Organzation_Description,
       Budget_Cumulative,
       Budget_Cumulative - NVL(LAG(Budget_Cumulative) OVER (PARTITION BY account_code,year_key ORDER BY month_key),0) nc_budget
  FROM BudgetTable
```

If you wanted to store this in the table (*not* recommended, as it violates normalization rules and creates possible inconsistent data down the road), you can easily plug this into the `USING` clause of your `MERGE` statement to update the table. But again, you're better off not storing it at all so that you only have one version of the truth, not two.

Comment: Thank you. Storing it into the table is very important to me so I will try your recommendation.

Comment: What happens if someone or some code later updates budget_cumulative for some row to a new value? Your nc_budget will be wrong. And some new person looking at the table in the future might not know which column is more trustworthy because neither is apparently derivative of the other. There's a reason for normalization rules.

Comment: Using `PARTITION BY account_code,year_key ORDER BY month_key` will not work for January and December of the previous year. Also, if a month's data is skipped then `LAG` will not notice this and then you will be comparing a month to several months ago rather than a month and the prior month.

Comment: @MT0, I understand OP's request to be that for January, the preceding month of December is *not* subtracted, their cumulative budget being zero'd out each year. "To calculate NC_BUDGET of month 01: NC_BUDGET is the same value as Budget". This is handled by the `NVL` so 0 is subtracted. Also, a skipped month would still result in assigning the correct amount of "additional budget" to the next month represented. If you skip 3 months and the aggregate has increased 3 months' worth, the difference is what's new. Seems to work in my mind.

Comment: The OP's requirements are poorly defined (unsurprising, given that this is the 4th time they've asked the question and have deleted the 3 previous attempts when they didn't include any business logic at all) and either your or my interpretation could be correct but there is nothing within the question that defines their business logic around the start of the year (only that the NC budget is the 2nd month's budget minus the 1st month's budget).

Answer (score 0):

Don't update the table (or store `NC_BUDGET` in the table as it is a derived column), create a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW BudgetView (
    Year_Key,
    Month_Key,
    Account_Code,
    Account_Description,
    Organzation_Description,
    Budget_Cumulative,
    NC_Budget
) AS
SELECT b.*,
       Budget_Cumulative
       - COALESCE(
           MAX(Budget_Cumulative) OVER (
             PARTITION BY account_code
             ORDER BY TO_DATE(year_key || '-' || month_key || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
             RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
           ),
           0
         )
FROM   BudgetTable b
```

Which, for the sample data (without the `NC_BUDGET` column):

```sql
CREATE TABLE BudgetTable (
    Year_Key NUMBER(4, 0) NOT NULL,
    Month_Key VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
    Account_Code NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Account_Description VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    Organzation_Description VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    Budget_Cumulative NUMBER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code)
);

INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '01', 23, 'Salary_Employee_1', '95684 - Jack''s', 10);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '01', 24, 'Salary_Employee_2', '95684 - Jack''s', 20);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '01', 25, 'Salary_Employee_3', '95684 - Jack''s', 30);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '01', 26, 'Salary_Employee_4', '95684 - Jack''s', 40);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '01', 27, 'Salary_Employee_5', '95684 - Jack''s', 50);

INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '02', 23, 'Salary_Employee_1', '95684 - Jack''s', 60);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '02', 24, 'Salary_Employee_2', '95684 - Jack''s', 70);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '02', 25, 'Salary_Employee_3', '95684 - Jack''s', 80);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '02', 26, 'Salary_Employee_4', '95684 - Jack''s', 90);
INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Year_Key, Month_Key, Account_Code, Account_Description, Organzation_Description, Budget_Cumulative) VALUES (2023, '02', 27, 'Salary_Employee_5', '95684 - Jack''s', 100);
```

Then the view contains:

| YEAR_KEY | MONTH_KEY | ACCOUNT_CODE | ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION | ORGANZATION_DESCRIPTION | BUDGET_CUMULATIVE | NC_BUDGET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 01 | 23 | Salary_Employee_1 | 95684 - Jack's | 10 | 10 |
| 2023 | 02 | 23 | Salary_Employee_1 | 95684 - Jack's | 60 | 50 |
| 2023 | 01 | 24 | Salary_Employee_2 | 95684 - Jack's | 20 | 20 |
| 2023 | 02 | 24 | Salary_Employee_2 | 95684 - Jack's | 70 | 50 |
| 2023 | 01 | 25 | Salary_Employee_3 | 95684 - Jack's | 30 | 30 |
| 2023 | 02 | 25 | Salary_Employee_3 | 95684 - Jack's | 80 | 50 |
| 2023 | 01 | 26 | Salary_Employee_4 | 95684 - Jack's | 40 | 40 |
| 2023 | 02 | 26 | Salary_Employee_4 | 95684 - Jack's | 90 | 50 |
| 2023 | 01 | 27 | Salary_Employee_5 | 95684 - Jack's | 50 | 50 |
| 2023 | 02 | 27 | Salary_Employee_5 | 95684 - Jack's | 100 | 50 |

---

If you must store it in the table (don't, it can get out-of-sync) then you can use a `MERGE` statement correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
MERGE INTO budgettable dst
USING (
  SELECT Budget_Cumulative
         - COALESCE(
             MAX(Budget_Cumulative) OVER (
               PARTITION BY account_code
               ORDER BY TO_DATE(year_key || '-' || month_key || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
               RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
             ),
             0
           ) AS new_nc_budget
  FROM   BudgetTable
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET nc_budget = src.new_nc_budget;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zo3uSfVq)